# With Azure, can I create a VLAN and put all my worker roles and VM's in there?

Tags: security, firewall, access-control-list, azure

Is it possible to create a sort of VLAN or private azure LAN thingy .. where I can put any new Workers or VM's in that VLAN?

one of the reasons is because I was hoping to create a SQL server on a VM (fine, that's simple) and then add the following firewall rules

=> Block all except
a) My work static IP. (easy)
b) My home static IP. (easy)
c) The VLAN of this private azure LAN (no idea)

the idea here, is I only want my workers (and our websites) that are part of our Azure subscription, to be the only places that can access the sql server + those 2 other 'special' ip's.

Sure, someone can break into one of the other VM's to then 'access' the sql-server-vm .. i get that ... but this is just one part of hardening down our server.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Virtual Networks

You can bring VLANs to Windows Azure using Virtual Networks; Azure supports Layer-3 overlays. The IP ranges that these Virtual Networks use are defined in RFC1918:

### IP Ranges

```
    10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255 (10/8 prefix), 
    172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255 (172.16/12 prefix), 
    192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 prefix)
```

So if you specify a certain virtual network as your group for new Workers and VMs, you could just add a firewall rule for the range your Virtual Network falls under.

[Windows Azure Config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn133803.aspx#BKMK_VNETFAQVNETConfig)

Comment: Think this answer should be updated with consideration for ARM portal. You can achieve the same desired outcome by using layer 3 subnets and creating, and configuring network security groups to filter traffic. NSG's allow filtering by service on specific ports, Azure tags (load balancer probes) as well as CIDR blocks.

Answer (score 1):

To add to [Harly Benoit](https://serverfault.com/users/207059/harley-benoit)'s answer - once you've created the virtual network on Azure, in order to deploy your worker (and web) roles on it you would need to specific the network and subnet you want to deploy them on to in their service configuration file -

```
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="WindowsAzure1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration" osFamily="1" osVersion="*" schemaVersion="2012-05.1.7"> 
  <Role name="WebRole1"> 
    <Instances count="1" /> 
. 
. 
</Role> 
  <NetworkConfiguration> 
    <VirtualNetworkSite name="mix-n-match" /> 
    <AddressAssignments> 
      <InstanceAddress roleName="WebRole1"> 
        <Subnets> 
          <Subnet name="FrontEnd" /> 
        </Subnets> 
      </InstanceAddress> 
    </AddressAssignments> 
  </NetworkConfiguration> 
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

I've written about mixing IaaS and PaaS on Azure [here](http://yossidahan.wordpress.com/2012/06/11/mix-n-match-on-windows-azure/)